# iCloud photo increasing "OTHER" storage section

Tags: storage

I have a strange complaint that I've been trying , and failing, to find an answer for.

I'm signed up to iCloud photo and have set it up to automatically minimise photos to save storage on my phone. I'm finding however that its eating up storage on my 64gb iPhone 6+. I think I've found out why and how its doing this and would love a find a way to shrink the amount of space its taking up.

Recently, when my photo storage had grown to over 13gb, I did a compete restore of my phone and recovered a lot of storage. I was delighted to see that my photo library had come down from 13GB to 2gb.

However, once I reinstalled other photo apps, like Flickr and Google Photo, they started once again to upload all my photos. My iCloud photo library rapidly increased from 2bg to 21gb!

Looking at the storage graph in iTunes it shows my photos still at around 2gb but the OTHER segment is around 20gb. If I check storage on the phone, it shows that Photos is 21gb. So obviously the huge OTHER segment is photos.

So what I have concluded after all this is that other photo apps (like Flickr) when set to back up photos from phone go through the whole library and download or decompress my total Photo library in order to upload it? Is anyone else having an issue with this or has had experience of it?  I have around 10,000 photos in iCloud.

Comment: My understanding is that iCloud tries to be smart about managing storage on your phone and doesn't seem to mind freely downloading/uploading media at will until the space *on the phone* gets closer to capacity. I grew so frustrated with the inability to have any control over iCloud Photo Library that I basically turned it off. So none of your problem surprises me and may simply be a testimony to the fact that iCloud Photo Library still appears to be having growing pains.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Does the phone malfunction in any way because of this data being stored in it?

Comment: Jaime, if it gets too large you can't do things like upgrade iOS etc. They claim these are buffered files that should be autoremoved, but they're not. I managed to free enough space to upgrade the phone from iOS 13 to 14 by removing a bunch of apps, but after the upgrade I still had 85G taken by "Other Storage". What finally helped was turning off iCloud storage in Settings→Photos, leading to Other taking <1G.